# AMPL Sum variables operator

Tags: ampl

I am trying to solve a set of problems using AMPL and add their objective values. However, the sum operator does not seem to work and only keeps getting updated to the most recent value.

```
set CASES := {1,2,3,4,5,6};
model modelFile.mod;
option solver cplex;
option eexit -123456789;
var total;
let total := 0;

for {j in CASES}
{
    reset data;
    data ("data" & j & ".dat")
    solve;
    display total_Cost; 
    let total := total + total_Cost;
    display total;
}
```

Sample Output:

```
CPLEX 12.6.3.0: optimal solution; objective 4.236067977
2 dual simplex iterations (0 in phase I)
total_Cost = 4.23607

total = 4.23607

CPLEX 12.6.3.0: optimal solution; objective 5.656854249
5 dual simplex iterations (0 in phase I)
total_Cost = 5.65685

total = 5.65685
```

where `total_cost` is the objective value from the optimization problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally realized that this happened due to the new keyword "reset data" that AMPL has. By changing the keyword to "update", the code works.

Comment: Right, you shouldn't have used "reset data" =). But switching to param is a good idea as well.

Answer (score 1):

Since AMPL is an [algebraic modeling language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_modeling_language) rather than a general-purpose programming language, variables in it denote optimization variables which are determined during the solution process. So each time you call `solve`, optimization variable `total` is reset. What you need here is a parameter which, unlike variable, is not changed during the optimization:

```
param total;
```

Comment: I tried doing it with param but that did not work either.

Comment: @statBeginner What exactly didn't work? Isn't it updated correctly?

Comment: No, there is no difference in the output between using param and var. But I do see your point now. I didn't check by using param without "reset data". If that works, it should be better conceptually than using var here. Agreed.